# check the check-boxes using array values in cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, html, cakephp

I am creating HTML checkboxes using **cakePHP** like :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('medicine_time.0', array('value' => 'morning', 'div' => false, 'label' => false)); ?> Morning &nbsp;
<?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('medicine_time.1', array('value' => 'noon', 'div' => false, 'label' => false)); ?> Afternoon &nbsp;
<?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('medicine_time.2', array('value' => 'eve', 'div' => false, 'label' => false)); ?> Evening &nbsp;
<?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('medicine_time.3', array('value' => 'night', 'div' => false, 'label' => false)); ?> Night &nbsp;
```

While this, i have an array which values will decide if ***checkbox*** will be **checked** or **not**

array :

```
[medicine_time] => Array
      (
         [0] => morning
         [1] => noon
         [2] => 0
         [3] => night
      )
```

Now, If I have ***morning***, my first checkbox with **same value** should be checked and so on. 
OR if I modify same array to :

```
[medicine_time] => Array
      (
         [0] => morning
         [1] => noon
         [2] => night
      )
```

would it help?

How could I achieve it? or any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this in controller:

```
$this->request->data['model_name'] = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_value'
      );
```

HTH.